# Prove that if $ab=k$ then if we times a by 2 we have to divide b by 2.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that if  $ab=k$ ,then $\implies 2a\frac b2 = k.$

My attemt :
$a=\frac kb \implies $
2$a=\frac {2k}{b}\implies $ 
$2ab=2k$ which then brings me back to $ ab=k$ and I've proven nothing .

Where have I gone wrong ?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: I have used the coding now.

Comment: @user57928 Can you give the original task?

Comment: I have now in my edit.

Comment: $ab=\frac22ab=2a\frac b2$ though it really depends what you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would address this question like this (I'm guessing this might be some sort of first-principles prove-everything-you-previously-thought-was-obvious course of study, where going into the fine detail is the point).

Think of the question as saying, "If $ab=k$, then $(2a)(2^{-1}b)=k$," where $2^{-1}$ is the notation used for the multiplicative inverse of $2$ (probably specified in whatever axioms you are working from). There feels like there's more content here so it might be psychologically easier to construct a proof.

It's perfectly okay to prove an equation by a long string of equalities going from one side to the other, so let's do that.

Start with $(2a)(2^{-1}b)$. Use whatever commutativity and associativity axioms you have to equate this to $(2^{-1}2)(ab)$. (Quite a few steps depending on what you've already proved for yourself. Of course, if you've already proved that any string of multiplications gives the same result no matter how you've bracketed it up this is a lot easier, but doing it step by step with the brackets makes it easier to see where the actual proving is going on.)

$(2^{-1}2)(ab)=1(ab)$ by definition of the multiplicative inverse.

$1(ab)=ab$ by definition of $1$.

The finally $ab=k$ by the hypothesis you you given. Stringing all these equalities together gives $(2a)(2^{-1}b)=k$ as you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Written in a such way the problem is quite trivial, clearly 
$$
ab = 2a\frac{b}{2},
$$

hence if $ab=k$ we get that $ 2a\frac{b}{2}=k$ (unless you are in char =2, but I think it is not the case). 
So, probably something is missing here.

Comment: Why is $ab= 2a\frac b2} ?

Comment: you are just multiplying for 2 and then dividing for 2, in formuals $$ ab = \frac{2}{2} ab = 2 \times a \times \frac{1}{2} \times b = 2a\frac{b}{2}$$